# Add Bootstrap Icon In Input's Placeholder

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-icons

I am trying to put Bootstrap search icon in the placeholder of `<input>`.
However as it is obvious that I cannot just write `<input type="text" placeholder="<i class='bi bi-search'>"` in the placeholder. I checked Stackoverflow and found that for **fontawesome** we can just simply put

`<input type="text" placeholder="&#xF002; Search" style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome" />` (For version 4.7+).

However What I want to know is there someway of achieving this with bootstrap also.
I checked the **bootstrap-icon CSS** file and found out this `.bi-search::before { content: "\f52a"; }`.
Edit:- I want to place it in the **Placeholder** not in the `<input>` field
Hope I made the question Clear.

Comment: override the bootstrap style in your css file

Comment: @לבנימלכה Can you please tell me how??

Comment: @Mrupsidown, not exactly, having the icon fixed in the input field is different and having it in placeholder is different.

Comment: @Mrupsidown The answers you're referring to for possible duplicates are based on **Fontawesome** and I already mentioned that in the question how it can be done using fontawesome fonts, the question is about bootstrap icons.

Comment: @a_man If you know how to do it with FontAwesome, you can basically do it with Bootstrap Icons too.  Its just another font-family (font-family:Arial, bootstrap-icons)

Comment: @GertB. I tried doing the same but I guess bootstrap icons do not have ''&#xF002;" this, I mean it's not working at all.

Comment: add the i element for the icon you want to use, inspect it look for the content property in css, there you will find the correct code

Comment: @GertB. doesn't seem to work. Also I really can't understand  why i am getting referred to the answer which is not even close to what I am asking. I wanted to put bootstrap icon in **PLACEHOLDER** of the <input> not in the input field itself.

Comment: Try this, ``<input type="text" placeholder="&#xf52a; Search " style="font-family:'bootstrap-icons', Arial">``

Comment: @pyrogrammer man, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton ^_^